# После изменений матчасти хоста docker перестал выполнять команду upgrade

Tags: docker

После того как увеличили размер диска хоста, появилась ошибка после команды apt upgrade:

```
# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.26-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of stop.
ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: libaio.so.1: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgrade issues.
Once the problem is resolved, run apt-get --fix-broken install to retry.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Ошибка не пропадает если удалить и заново установить **mysql**, раньше была такая ошибка из-за **библиотеки aio**(было определено что процессор выбран не тот), но тогда просто добавил *--privileged*, и всё стало норм, но сейчас это не помогает.

Команду *dpkg --configure -a* пробовал, но то же самое. 
Сама команда: *docker run -it -p 80:80 --net="host" --privileged -v /home/administrator/docker_site/:/var/www apache2_ufw_mysql_php_iit  /bin/sh*

Comment: [судя по всему](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/5430) 1. --privileged надо убрать. 2. и отключить правила для mysqld у apparmor-а

Comment: Нужно было просто кеш apparmor почистить,

apparmor_parser --purge-cache
apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld

Comment: `apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` — это и есть [отключение](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apparmor_parser.8.html) правил для mysqld.

Comment: А есть ли разница между apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld и apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld?